# Check if string does not contain strings from the list

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```py
mystring = ["reddit", "google"]
mylist = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
for mystr in mystring:
    if any(x not in mystr for x in mylist):
        print(mystr)
```

I'm expecting that this should return only `"google"`. But for some reason it returns both `"reddit"` and `"google"`.

Comment: `if all(x not in mystr for x in mylist):` ?

Comment: In python it's a convention to use `snake_case` for your variables. Also if you have a list, make the variable name plural e.g. `my_strings`. This means you don't have to say odd things like `for mystr in mystring`. These are just nitpicks, but following these conventions makes it easier to understand your own code

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your use of `any` and `not in` contradicts itself. You want to check either for `all` like this:

```
if all(x not in mystr for x in mylist):
    print mystr
```

Or just check for `not any` (which is more readable in my opinion):

```
if not any(x in mystr for x in mylist):
    print mystr
```

Both of these versions can be a one-liner by the way (instead of your loop), if you use list comprehension (but that is just a matter of taste, or if you prefer to print out one line of results instead of one line for every result):

```
mystring = ["reddit", "google"]
mylist = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
print [s for s in mystring if not any(x in s for x in mylist)]
```

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want any of these letters to appear in your strings, then you should use:

```
all(x not in mystr for x in mylist)
```

and not `any`:

```
mystring = ["reddit", "google"]
mylist = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
for mystr in mystring:
  if all(x not in mystr for x in mylist):
    print mystr
```

prints only

```
google
```

Answer (score 0):

To ensure the input string does not contain **any** char from the list, your condition should be:

```
...
if not any(x in mystr for x in mylist):
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code working, just with different variable names:

```
words = ["reddit", "google"]
chars = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
for word in words:
    print(word,":",[char not in word for char in chars]) #explanation help
    if all(char not in word for char in chars):
        print("none of the characters is contained in",word)
```

Its output:

```
reddit : [True, True, True, False]
google : [True, True, True, True]
none of the characters is contained in google
```

As you see you only need to change `any` to `all`.
This is because you want to test whether none of the characters is contained in the word, so whether **all** list elements as shown in the output are true, not just any of them.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
s = ["reddit","google"]
l = ["a","b","c","d"]
for str in s:
    if all(x not in str for x in l):
       print(str)
```