# Twitter bot not to interact with certain phrases

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm making a Twitter bot that replies or likes tweets. I want it not to interact with certain phrases. For example: don't interact with tweets that have the phrase ''yellow banana". Here's my code and my attempted solution isn't working. I'm trying to get the tweet text and compare it to the "frases_naocurtir" variable that has phrase that there shouldn't be interaction. It keeps picking up these tweets and interacting.

```
rc = random.choice(frases)
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets, rc).items(1):
    time.sleep(random.randint(time_init, time_final))
    try:
        cstatus = api.get_status(tweet.id, tweet_mode="extended")
        text = cstatus.full_text

        time.sleep(random.randint(time_init, time_final))
        
        if rc in frases_curtir and text not in frases_naocurtir and vaicurtir != 0:
            print('\nFrase buscada curtir: ' + str(rc))
            tweet.favorite()
            print('\nTweet curtido de: ' + tweet.user.screen_name + '\nTweet ID: ' + str(tweet.id) + 
            '\nTweet date: ' + str(tweet.created_at.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')))
            time.sleep(random.randint(time_init, time_final))

            if vairesponder != 0 and vaicurtir == 0:
                rc = random.choice(frases_responder)
                continue
            if vairesponder == 0 and vaicurtir != 0:
                rc = random.choice(frases_curtir)
                continue
            if vairesponder != 0 and vaicurtir != 0:
                rc = random.choice(frases)
                continue
```

Comment: So if `text` is `"I have a yellow banana"`, and `frases_naocurtir` is `["yellow banana", "green apple"]`, then indeed `"I have a yellow banana"` is not contained in `["yellow banana", "green apple"]` and `text not in frases_naocurtir` is true. You meant something different: *none* of the strings from `frases_naocurtir` *is contained in* `text`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58641898/check-if-string-not-contains-strings-from-the-list